# Creating multiple arrays using one for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm a newbie to Java and here I am trying to minimize the amount of code I've written.
I want to add elements to 2 arrays of the same size using only one for loop. I tried many ways but it ended up adding the same elements to both arrays. How can I loop twice and add different elements?

This's how I did it using two for loops...

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int size = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int[] arr1 = new int[size];
        int[] arr2 = new int[size];
        String[] elem1 = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = Integer.parseInt(elem1[i]);
        }


        String[] elem2 = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            arr2[j] = Integer.parseInt(elem2[j]);
        }

        System.out.println(LargestPair( arr1, arr2, size));
    }
```

Comment: I would just continue as you've gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] elem1 = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
String[] elem2 = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    arr1[i] = Integer.parseInt(elem1[i]);
    arr2[i] = Integer.parseInt(elem2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```java
 private static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
        int size = Integer.parseInt(SCANNER.nextLine());

        Integer[] arr1 = getAsIntArray(size);
        Integer[] arr2 = getAsIntArray(size);

        System.out.println(LargestPair(arr1, arr2, size));
    }

    private static Integer[] getAsIntArray(int size) {
        System.out.print("Enter " + size + " space separated elements: ");
        return Arrays.stream(SCANNER.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Edited to use a more functional/concise approach